# Is the set of probability distributions with two mass points and finite 4-th moment compact and closed in the weak{*} topology?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is the set of probability distributions with two mass points and finite 4-th moment compact and closed in the weak{*} topology.

In particular, I would like to see the difference between the following two sets.

That is we are looking at the set 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}_1=\left \{ F:  F=(1-t) \delta_{x_1}+t \delta_{x_2}, \, t\in[0,1], \, x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}, \int x^4 dF(x)=c  \right\}\\
\mathcal{P}_2=\left \{ F:  F=(1-t) \delta_{x_1}+t \delta_{x_2}, \, t\in[0,1], \, x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}, \int x^4 dF(x)\le c  \right\}
\end{align}
for some $c>0$.  (Note that all we did is changed equality to inequality).

**Proof that the sets are closed:**

Let $ F_n \in \mathcal{P}_2$   converge weakly to $F$.  Weak convergence is equivalent to 
\begin{align}
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \int f(x) dF_n(x) \ge  \int f(x) dF(x)
\end{align}
for all continuous function $f(x)$.  So, we have that
\begin{align}
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \int x^4 dF_n(x)= c \ge  \int x^4 dF(x)
\end{align}

This implies that $\mathcal{P}_2$ is closed. **What about  $\mathcal{P}_1$?**

**Proof that the sets are compact:**

By [Prokhorov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem) set is tight if it is closed and tight.

The set is tight if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $a$ such that 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[|X|>a] \le \epsilon
\end{align}

Since we are imposing a 4-th moment constraint by Markov inequality we have that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[|X|>a] \le  \frac{E[X^4]}{a^4} =  \frac{c^2}{a^4}
\end{align}
Choose $a^4=\frac{\epsilon}{c^2}$ and we have that both $\mathcal{P}_1$ and $\mathcal{P}_2$ are tight sets.

This implies that  $\mathcal{P}_2$ is compact. **What about  $\mathcal{P}_1$?**

Comment: $\mathcal{P}_1$ is closed in $\mathcal{P}_2$, and closed in compact is compact.

Comment: @yanko. Sure, that is clear. Is $\mathcal{P}_1$  closed set in space of all probability distributions on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is closed in $\mathcal{P}_2$ because it is the pre-image of the singelton $\{c\}$ of the functional $F\mapsto \int x^4 dF$, and being close in a close set implies being close. right?

Comment: @yanko Yes. Good point. So, to summarize: Both $\mathcal{P}_1$ and  $\mathcal{P}_2$ are closed and compact, right?

Comment: yes exactly right.

Comment: @yanko Ok. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @yanko I was wondering if you could take a look at this question that I posted earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370082/maximum-of-exzm-for-z-standard-normal-and-x-independent-of-z-two

Comment: @yanko. Please take a look at a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\mathcal{P}_1$ is not closed. For $x>0$ define $\mu_x=(1-p)\delta_0+p\delta_x$ where $p=c/x^4$. Then $\mu_x\in\mathcal{P}_1$ but 
$\mu_x\to\delta_0$ as $x\to\infty$ and $\delta_0\notin \mathcal{P}_1$.