# Concavity of $f(x)=E[| x +Z|^m]$ where $Z$ is standard normal.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $Z$ be a symmetric distribution. Considere a function 
\begin{align}
f(x)=E[| x +Z|^m]
\end{align}
for $x>0$.  We assume that $m \ge 0$.

For simplicity, let assume that  $Z$ is standard normal(but it would be nice to show this for more general $Z$).

**My question:**

Can we show for what values of $m$ the funciton $f(x)$ is concave?

I know that the non-central moments of Gaussian has an expression in term of hypergeometric function which can probably be used to show this.  However, I would like to avoid that route. As I don't think it is very simple.

This question was inspired by the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370082/maximum-of-exzm-for-z-standard-normal-and-x-independent-of-z-two)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised 8 August.
Since $|z+x|^m$ is convex for all $z\in\mathbb R$ and $m\ge 1$, if  $m\ge 1$ then $f$ is convex.

In general, if $m>0$ then $f(x)$ is convex near $x=0$.  This follows from the formula $$f(x) = 2^{m/2}\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{1+m}2\big)}{\sqrt{\pi}} M(-m/2, 1/2;  -x^2/2),$$  where $M$ is the confluent hypergeometric function, a.k.a. ${{}_1}F_1$.  The Taylor expansion of $M(-m/2,1/2; -x^2/2) $ starts out  $1+\frac m 2 x^2 +\ldots$ from which $f''(0)>0$ follows.  Thus $f$ is concave for no value of $m>0$.

Added 16 August, revised 18 August.  I believe that for $0<m<1$, there exists an $x_m>0$ such that $f$ is convex on $[0, x_m]$ and concave on $[x_m,\infty)$. But I don't see a proof yet.

This would imply that, in the case $m<1$,  the upper concave envelope $f^*$ of $f$ interpolates linearly between $f(0)$ and $f(x_m)$ on the range $[0,x_m]$ and is equal to $f$ on $[x_m,\infty)$, which in turn has implications for the OP's motivating optimization problem.